# Android tablet has 45 GB free but shows low space warning

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

So this tablet is pretty new. Hardly even used it. But when I tried to put videos and large apps onto it, it constantly gives me a "insufficient space" warning. it comes with 57.61GB of storage ( no external SD or anything) and I can't add anything once it reaches "45GB free"

It has not been rooted. It has hit 0% battery once but was on charge and it shut down (yes, bad idea to run it but it's battery dropped from 14% to 0)

I've used all sorts of apps to identify how much space remains and even my computer says it has 45GB free.

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

Comment: [insufficient-memory' tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) should be of help to you. See the frequently asked questions in that tag to investigate and resolve. Also, please [edit] to mention  device particulars . Please add snapshot of memory space as shown by apps. You will find recommended apps in questions on that tag. Welcome to Android Enthusiasts

Comment: It seems you have /sdcard on a different partition than /data. What device is it? Not clear from K101.